# Scalaz Kleisli usage benefits

Tags: scala, scalaz, kleisli

In [scalaz](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/snapshots/archive/org/scalaz/scalaz_2.11/7.2.0-SNAPSHOT/scalaz_2.11-7.2.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar/!/index.html#scalaz.Kleisli) `Kleisli[M[_], A, B]` is a wrapper of `A => M[B]`, which allows composition of such functions. For instance, if `M[_]` is monad I can compose `Kleisli[M, A, B]` and `Kleisli[M, B, C]` with `>=>` to get `Kleisli[M, A, C]`.

In a nutshell, `Kleisli` provides fancy `andThens` depending on `M`. Is it correct ? Are there other benefits of using `Kleisli`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are two benefits as examples—I'm sure you could come up with others.

First, it can be useful to abstract over different arrows, such as `Kleisli[M, ?, ?]` and `? => ?`. For example, I can write a generic function that will apply an endomorphism a certain number of times.

```
def applyX10[Arr[_, _]: Category, A](f: Arr[A, A]) =
  List.fill(10)(Endomorphic(f)).suml
```

Now I can use this on e.g. `Int => Int` or `Kleisli[Option, Int, Int]`:

```
val f = (_: Int) + 1

val k = Kleisli.kleisli[Option, Int, Int] {
  case i if i % 2 == 0 => Some(i * 3)
  case _ => None
}
```

And then:

```
scala> applyX10(f).run(1)
res0: Int = 11

scala> applyX10[=?>, Int](k).run(2)
res1: Option[Int] = Some(118098)
```

(Note that `A =?> B` is just an alias for `Kleisli[Option, A, B]`.)

Second, the fact that `Kleisli[F, ?, ?]` has a monad instance if `F` does can also be useful. See for example [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25950063/334519) for a demonstration of how you can use monadic composition with `ReaderT`, which is just an alias for `Kleisli`.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to _grok_ it as follows: (1) `Kleisli` in general as an abstraction over different arrows (2) special cases: e.g. `ReaderT`,  reader monad, etc.

Comment: Well, for a monad `M`, `Kleisli[M, ?, ?]` is _an_ arrow.