# Using Monad Transformer from Option -> Either

Tags: scala, monads

Given the following method,

```
scala> def f(x: Option[String]): Either[String, Int] = x match {
        case Some(x) => try { Right(x.toInt) } 
                        catch { 
                          case _:  NumberFormatException => Left(s"Not an int: $x") 
                        }
        case None    => Left("No String present.")
      }
f: (x: Option[String])Either[String,Int]
```

**testing**

```
scala> f(None)
res0: Either[String,Int] = Left(No String present.)

scala> f(Some("44"))
res2: Either[String,Int] = Right(44)

scala> f(Some("zipp"))
res3: Either[String,Int] = Left(Not an int: zipp)
```

How would a Monad transformer be used here?

Note - I don't know if it's a good example since it's so short (and the pattern match might be the cleanest way), but I'm curious anyway.

Comment: Monad transformers are kind of confusingly named—they're more like tools to help with composing monads than transformers from one monadic type to another.

Comment: I'd use a `map` here and Scalaz gives you nicer tools for going from `Option` to `Either`, but the basic approach looks reasonable to me.

Comment: `Option.toRight` in the standard lib seems pretty nice to me.

Comment: @m-z Oh right, that's in the standard library, not Scalaz. :)

Comment: Got any good examples?

Comment: Of monad transformers? There are a [number of questions on here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=monad-transformers+scala). [Here's a potential starting point](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25950063/334519).